# How to add custom folders to webpack/watchpack from within a plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm looking for a way to hook up to the webpack watcher (watchpack) from the plugin. There is a very esoteric need to add some files and folders to watch from the plugin. I tried multiple different approaches like

```js
compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('SomePlugin', (compilation) => {
    const apiDir = path.join(compiler.options.context, 'src', 'api')
    const files = fs.readdirSync(apiDir).map((file) => path.join(apiDir, file))
        compilation.fileDependencies.addAll(files)
})
```

But it only adds **existing** `files` to the watcher. Any known ways to add folders so whenever file is created/updated/deleted, the plugin is invoked again?

I tried looking into webpack and watchpack source code, but no luck there. Whatever I invoke, it doesn't update the watcher.